# Error in tm package while topic modelling

Tags: r, lda, tm, topic-modeling

I am running into an error while trying to make a corpus object from the `tm` package in R.

The data have been scraped from a website and I have included the full code below so you can run and see how the data were gathered and the tibble was created. The very last line of code is where I am getting stuck! (I have modified the loop so it should run in a few seconds).

Any help would be appreciated. :)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
########################################## 
# WEB SCRAPING FROM SCHOLARLYKITCHEN.COM #
##########################################

# create loop that iteratively adds page numbers onto
# keep the loop numbers small for testing before full data is pulled in
output <- character()
for (i in 1:2) { 
  
  article.links <- paste0("https://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/archives/page/", i ,"/") %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(".list-article__title") %>%
    html_nodes("a") %>% 
    html_attr("href")
  
  output <- c(output, article.links) 
  
}

# get all comments
get.comments <- function(output) {
  article.page <- read_html(output)
  article.comments <- article.page %>% html_nodes(".comment") %>% html_text() %>% trimws(which = "both")
  return(article.comments)
}

text <- sapply(output, FUN = get.comments, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

# get all dates
get.dates <- function(output) {
  article.page <- read_html(output)
  article.comments <- article.page %>% html_nodes(".comment__meta__date") %>% html_text() %>% trimws(which = "both")
  return(article.comments)
}

dates <- sapply(output, FUN = get.dates, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

# create the made df for the analysis
df <- tibble(
    text = unlist(text, recursive = TRUE), # unlist is needed because sapply (for some reason) creates a list
    dates = unlist(dates, recursive = TRUE)
)

# extract dates from meta data
df$dates <- as.character(gsub(",","",df$dates))
df$dates <- as.Date(df$dates, "%B%d%Y")


###################
# TOPIC MODELLING #
###################
library(tm)
library(topicmodels)

# create df ready for topic modelling
# this needs to have very specifically names columns

df.tm <- df[-2] # create dupelicate for backup (dates not needed for topic modelling yet)
df.tm$doc_id <- row.names(df) # create a unique id for each row as is needed by the tm package
df.tm <- df.tm[c(2,1)] # reorders the columns

# From the comments text, create the corpus
corpus <- VCorpus(DataframeSource(df))
```

Error is the below

```
Error in DataframeSource(df) : 
  all(!is.na(match(c("doc_id", "text"), names(x)))) is not TRUE
```

Comment: punt: do you mean to use `df.tm` in the last line?

Comment: My R is currently occupied but I will try this an get back to you as soon as I test it.
If this is my error I will be very upset with myself! lol

Comment: Yes, there we have it! After all that code I made the stupidest error.

Fixed and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`DataframeSource()` requires the df to have a document index in its first column, and it must be labeled "doc_id".

Try:

```
df_with_id <- rowid_to_column(df, var = "doc_id") # Alternatively, generate a doc index that better represents your collection of documents.
corpus <- VCorpus(DataframeSource(df))

<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 1
Content:  documents: 141
```